# Format PHP echo in HTML

Tags: php, html, email, echo

this can´t be so hard, so obviouslly there is something I´m not seeing.

If anyone can spot what the problem is and give me a clue, I´d really appreciate it!

Thanks and have a great day!

```
<?php     
$code = '1221';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';


// THIS LINE IS WHAT I CAN´T GET PRINTED ON SCREEN:
$message .= '<?php echo $code; ?>';


$message .= '</body></html>';

echo $message. " ";
?>
```

Comment: So you want to print the actual PHP code on the page? Do you want it to say "$code", or 1221? What's up with the $header variable - it's never used. Also the X-mailer line is just kind of hanging out not doing anything.

Comment: Are you wanting to use this print the message to screen or are you trying to create the variables (`$headers`, $message`, etc) to pass in to a `mail()` type function?

Comment: Thank you very much for writing, Rob Rutche and qooplmao! Rob Rutche, yes, I erase some lines from the code that I didn´t think add any context to my question, but as it is, you´re absolutely right, there´re some no use lines. Qooplmao, I was trying to HTML format en email message, but I couldn´t find how to format a PHP variable passed through Unity 3D. Thanks you both again!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to see `1221` on the screen and not the php code. Therefore

```
$message .= $code;
```

or

```
$message .= "$code";
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, Engel, that´s perfect! And what if you want to print it to screen with  the same style than the previous line? I mean something like $message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">$code;</p>'; (Obviouslly that won´t work) Thank you!

Comment: Never mind, got it, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!!                  
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">';
$message .= $code;
$message .= '</p>';